# Streaming audio and video from Android to SmartTv Samsung

Tags: android, server, streaming, webrtc, samsung-smart-tv

My problem is transmission between android and smart tv.

I tried use WebRTC, but not worked, because smart tv not have chrome,  it uses a browser particular samsung.

I have to capture the real-time video using Android Camera, and send them to the server, then the smart tv should read them through the browser or something else.

How I do this?

I saw that can be useful to RtpStream class, MediaRecorder from Android.

what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the encoding part: plenty of free encoders on android, for example [wowza gocoder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wowza.gocoder&hl=en)

for the server: something like adobe media server/wowza, i suggest wowza because it's very reliable, cheaper than ams and easier to [setup](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-RTMP-based-encoder), considering the fact that most smart tvs support HLS streaming you should enable it on the "Playback Types" list or just check what your tv supports and enable that, you have plenty of supported protocols

for the playback: that depends on your smarttv models, as i was saying previously if your tv supports hls you might just need a browser with a  tag pointing to the url